How do people track/budget credit card payments in personal finance software
I'm not looking for recommendations on software here, I use Monarch and I'm happy with it. I'm also not asking about techniques to pay off my cards. This is about how people track paying off their credit cards.
I have a credit card that I'm paying off and I'm not sure how to track that clearly in my personal finance software. In an ideal world where I didn't carry a balance, I'd just track spending on my card as an expense in whatever category, and then pay it off each month with a transfer from checking (debit my checking and credit the card) that has no impact on my monthly summary, so I see the spending in food, utilities, etc, and then the impact of the payment itself is zero. If there's interest, that's another expense category, but no big deal.
My issue is that I'm carrying a balance and I'm paying it down, but I'm trying to track the "cash flow" portion of how much money I'm paying on my card (since it comes out of my monthly income so I pay as much as I can, but I want to see that in the overall picture), but I also have interest on the card - if I track the interest as an expense and the payment as another expense, I'm effectively counting the interest twice (once itself and once as part of my payment). Same thing for any spending on the card - if I put $100 in groceries on the card, it's an expense, but then I don't want to count it again when I make a payment on the card.
Not sure if this makes sense, but here are the options I can see:

(What I'm currently doing) Credit card payments are just transfers, and I count spending and interest as my expenses. Downside is that when I look at my monthly spending summary, it doesn't show what I'm paying towards my card as part of my monthly spending, and I can't easily tell if I could be paying more or if it's too much.
Count credit card payments as an expense (and then don't count the interest - hide it from my spending). This would make credit card payments part of my monthly allocation, but then I'd essentially get double-reported for any spending on my card (groceries on the card would count as groceries and as part of the payment).
Count credit card payments as an expense, but don't count any other spending on my cards (interest or usage) towards my budget. Spending on the card is very limited, but I don't like the idea of any spending that I use the card for not showing in my summary at all.

Am I missing a better solution? How do others do this effectively? I really I'm kind of mixing an income/expense summary and a cash flow summary so maybe there's no way to reconcile it clearly.

To me, it doesn't make sense to put additional charges on a card while you're paying interest... Can you use a debit card or cash until the CC is fully paid off? This also has the benefit of simplifying your accounting.

You've nearly answered your own question here: I really I'm kind of mixing an income/expense summary and a cash flow summary so maybe there's no way to reconcile it clearly.
You need to decide what is the critical information you need to get out of your finance software, and (depending on the capabilities of the software) that may guide how you organise the information that you're feeding in.  Ideally, your software will offer a range of reports including Cash Flow reports - but I don't know Monarch at all.
In my view, your Option 2 is the worst option.  You correctly identified that categorising each credit card purchase as an expense AND categorising your monthly payment towards the C.C. balance as an expense will give you incorrect reporting.  Your expenses will always be reported as higher than they actually are.
Your Option 3 could work - if the ONLY thing that you were interested in is your monthly cash flow.  Having one expense recorded per month (the transfer of money from your bank account to the credit card account) certainly keeps things ... simple.  The major disadvantage is that it deliberately obscures a great deal of useful information. If you want to analyse whether you should cut back on Clothes purchases or Dining Out purchases, your financial records won't be any help at all.
Your Option 1 looks the best to me, where you record each individual purchase made using your credit card as an expense, along with any interest charge.  The monthly transfer from your bank account to your credit card is not an expense, it's just a transfer of funds that doesn't make you richer or poorer.  This will allow accurate reporting of your income and expenditure.  Whether you are able to also produce useful Cash Flow reports will depend on the capability of your software.
You say that "I'm carrying a balance and I'm paying it down" (Good!) and "I can't easily tell if I could be paying more or if it's too much".  The glib answer is that you'll minimise your interest payments if you pay as much as you can afford each month to minimise your residual credit card balance.  That is, pay off as much as your income allows while still maintaining a reasonable minimum balance in your bank account in case of unforeseen needs.

As you mention, there are two ways to think about your finances - as income/expense and as cash flow. When you use credit cards extensively, you have a large imbalance between the expense and the cash flows which can be difficult to manage.
Making a payment on the card is not an expense. It is a cash flow. It did not change your wealth, only how much cash on hand you have. The interest is an expense, but should not be conflated with the payment - you get charged the interest whether you make a payment or not. The cash flow should be tracked, but more to make sure that you don't overdraw bank accounts, not as an "expense".
Most financial software packages look at your finances from one aspect well, and the other as a side feature. The one I use focuses on account balances, and looking at your overall financial picture as income and expense takes a bit of work. Others track your overall expenses well but don't easily give you a picture on where your account balances are.
If you are consistently carrying a balance and trying to pay it off at the same time, it's like bailing water out of a boat that has a leak.  You might get all of the water out eventually, but it's hard to know how much progress you're making.  Also, every single purchase you make is costing you more interest until you get the card paid off. So, continuing the boat metaphor, every time you bail some water out, a little bit splashes back in.
If you're serious about getting your cards paid off, my advice is to stop using them. Pay for more things with cash, and tie automatic bills to your bank account rather than your credit cards. That will let you get the balance paid off and stop paying interest. HOWEVER, it will require good discipline to make sure you don't overdraw your bank accounts and incur penalties, making the problem worse.  You might even find that you spend less, either because of a psychological change of using cash or because you know you don't have the money to spend.

In the personal finance software I use, credit cards are loan accounts. Transactions can be downloaded from my bank, so I automatically have a full list of credit card purchases. Making a payment on that debt is recorded as a transfer from a savings or checking account to the credit card account. As others have noted, this transfer is not considered a purchase; the purchases are tracked (and assigned to budget categories, either automatically or manually) in the credit card account.
This may be a bit different in other personal finance packages which use different accounting models, but the same basic flow will apply. The user clues for your personal finance software will almost certainly have examples of how to set up and use a credit card account.
